# SEO: How to make Google show correct page during search for a specific keywords

Tags: seo, google-search, landing-page

My company sells a lot of timber such as decking, landscape timber, timber sleepers, etc. We specify this in the front page of our website -that we sells decking, landscape timber, etc.

Lately we want to focus so Google shows a correct landing page for focused keywords such as "timber sleepers",  "landscape timber". So I create a dedicated landing page for "timber sleepers", and ask Google to fetch it.

The problem is: whenever I search "timber sleepers", Google keep showing the **front page** of our website, because we have those keywords in the front page.

Google also does not show my new "Timber Sleepers" page at all. It seems that it only shows my website URL once (which is the front page).

What will be the best way to optimize this? Does this happen because I just made the changes recently (about 3 days).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time is certainly a factor.  I would expect Google to take at least a week and maybe as much as a month to properly index your pages and to show them for the targeted searches.

You also need to do more than just create the page and ask Google to fetch it.  Here is a short checklist:

- Use the targeted keywords prominently in the page title.  For example, a good title for a landing page might be "Timber Sleepers - MyCompanyName".
- Use the targeted keyword at least once in the text on the page.
- Have unique content on the page (certainly text, but unique photos can help too)
- Make sure that the landing page will actually satisfy the user better than the home page (deep links into the correct product pages and other specific info that is easier to access than the home page.)
- **Link to the page** -- You need powerful links from the rest of your site.  Certainly link to it from the home page, but also consider putting it in the navigation of your site or link to it from all the product pages that would fall under the category.

Comment: Since my "Timber Sleepers" page is a listing of product with "Timber Sleepers" category, will it be better to add extra content before / after the listing? Will this somehow improve the rank?

Comment: A list of products is fine unique content as long as that same list isn't already on the home page.   If you add to the page, figure out what users coming from search engines are looking for other than a list of products and add that.